# How do I prevent clients from creating an instance of the model class via the default init method?

Tags: django

One of the properties in the model class is a generated value.
Thus I want to limit the user from inserting their own opaque string.
I want the user to use one of my manager methods to create an instance.
Is there a way to prevent the user in my use case ?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to "hide" the value by actually giving the field a different name, and only exposing it via a property:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    _real_field = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    @property
    def fake_field(self):
        return self._real_field
```

This way, you can set `real_field` in your Manager, but only document the existence of `fake_field`.

The downside of this is that you would have to use `_real_field` in your queries.